# $\varphi$-function and the multiplicative property.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Any answers with rings and groups will only become more strange to my, since I haven't started my first algebra class yet. Thank you in advance. So this is the beginning of the proof in my book:

**Proposition:**
Let $m$ and $n$ be relatively prime natural numbers. Then $\varphi(mn)=\varphi(m)\varphi(n)$.

**Proof:**
Put $N=mn$ and let $r:\mathbb{Z}/N\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}/m \times \mathbb{Z}/n$ be the remainder map. We know that $r$ is a bijective map (by a lemma which I understand, so this is not crucial). If we can prove that
\begin{align*}
r((\mathbb{Z}/N)^{\ast})= (\mathbb{Z}/m)^{\ast} \times (\mathbb{Z}/n)^{\ast}
\end{align*}
Then we are done, since $r$ then restricts to give a bijective map from $(\mathbb{Z}/N)^{\ast}$ to $(\mathbb{Z}/m)^{\ast} \times (\mathbb{Z}/n)^{\ast}$ I derive this part from the fact that (if it's true that its a bijection) the cardinallity of  $(\mathbb{Z}/N)^{\ast}$ is equal to the cardinallity of ${(\mathbb{Z}/m)^{\ast} \times (\mathbb{Z}/n)^{\ast}}$. Which again is equal (at least in my head) to $\varphi(mn)=\varphi(m)\varphi(n)$.

Now the author writes: Thus we need to prove that $\gcd(X,N)=1$ iff $\gcd([X]_{m},m)=1$ and $\gcd([X]_{n},n)=1$.

It is the last two lines I'm not so sure about, - how do I see this ?

Comment: What does $[X]_m$ stand for?

Comment: $x$ **mod** $m$.

Comment: In that case it may be helpful to note that $\text{gcd}([X]_m,m)=1 \Longleftrightarrow \text{gcd}(X,m)=1$.

Comment: Ok, I see that. In fact I've proved it in an early exercise. Bu why dont the author want to prove that $\gcd(X,N)=1$ iff $\gcd(X,m)=1$ and $\gcd(X,n)=1$ instead ?

Comment: Not sure exactly, but probably because you are working with the map $r$. The image of $r$ is a subset of $\Bbb Z/m \times \Bbb Z/n$ and all the elements of the image are of the form $([X]_m,[X]_n)$.

Comment: Ye, I was about to write that too. Ok, så it makes a bit sense now. I'll try to write the entire proof with my own explanation, and then I'll post a new question, to see if I got it all right.