# Multiplicative property of $\varphi$-function - Interpretation.

Tags: abstract-algebra

This is an extension of [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/477169/varphi-function-and-the-multiplicative-property), where I was looking for some hints to prove the following. It's the proof from my textbook, though with my thoughts and additional lemmas/remarks.

Is my interpretation somehow right ?

**Lemma 1:**
Suppose that $N=n_{1}\cdots n_{t}$, where $n_{1},\ldots,n_{t}\in\mathbb{N}\setminus\{0\}$ and $\gcd(n_{i},n_{j})=1$ if $i\neq j$. The the remainder map
\begin{align}
r:\mathbb{Z}/N\Rightarrow\mathbb{Z}/n_{1}\times\cdots\times\mathbb{Z}/n_{t}
\end{align}
is bijective.

**Lemma 2:**
Let $m,n\in\mathbb{Z}$. Then
\begin{align*}
\gcd(m,n)=\gcd(m-qn,n)=\gcd([m]_{n},n) \ \ \ for \ every \ q\in\mathbb{Z}.
\end{align*}

**Lemma 3:**
Let $a,b,c\in\mathbb{Z}$. If $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime and $a$ and $c$ are relatively prime, then $a$ and $bc$ are relatively prime.

**Remark 1:**
Let $A$ and $B$ be two sets in $\mathbb{Z}$. Then $|A\times B| = |A|\cdot|B|$. We also remember $|A|=|B|$ iff there is a bijection between $A$ and $B$.

**Proposition:**
Let $m$ and $n$ be relatively prime natural numbers. Then
\begin{align*}
\varphi(mn)=\varphi(m)\varphi(n)
\end{align*}

Put $N=mn$ and let $r:\mathbb{Z}/N\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}/m \times \mathbb{Z}/n$ be the remainder map. We know that $r$ is a bijective map by a Lemma 1. If we can prove that
\begin{align*}
r((\mathbb{Z}/N)^{\ast})= (\mathbb{Z}/m)^{\ast} \times (\mathbb{Z}/n)^{\ast},
\end{align*}
then we are done, since $r$ then restricts to give a bijective map from $(\mathbb{Z}/N)^{\ast}$ to $(\mathbb{Z}/m)^{\ast} \times (\mathbb{Z}/n)^{\ast}$ and by Remark 1 we have ${|(\mathbb{Z}/N)^{\ast}| = |(\mathbb{Z}/m)^{\ast}| \cdot |(\mathbb{Z}/n)^{\ast}|}$ which is equivalent to $\varphi(mn)=\varphi(m)\varphi(n)$.

Thus we need to prove that $\gcd(X,mn)=1$ iff $\gcd([X]_{m},m)=1$ and $\gcd([X]_{n},n)=1$. This is because $r$ maps a set containing only of relatively primes to a set containing only of relatively primes of the form $([X]_{m},[X]_{n})$.

So by Lemma 2, $\gcd([X]_{m},m)=1$ and $\gcd([X]_{n},n)=1$ if and only if $\gcd(X,m)=1$ and $\gcd(X,n)=1$. But this implies that $\gcd(X,mn)=1$ by Lemma 3, and this completes the proof.